# flutter cubit to cubit communication not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bloc

NOTE: POST UPDATED!

I have two cubits one of them is `LoginCubit` which is responsible for login actions and has 3 different states( `LoginLoading`, `LoginSuccess`, `LoginFailure`). The other cubit is `AuthCubit` which has 4 states(`AuthInitial`, `AuthLoading`, `Authenticated`, `Unauthenticated`) and it is responsible for authentication events.

If the user is logged in (that means if the state is `LoginSuccess`), then the `AuthState` must be converted to `Authenticated`). At this point, I listen to `LoginState` from my `AuthCubit`, if any state changes occur. This is the code where `AuthCubit`  listens `LoginState`.

**AuthCubit**

```
  final IsSignInUseCase isSignInUseCase;
  final SignOutUseCase signOutUseCase;
  final ReadAuthFromStorageUseCase readAuthFromStorageUseCase;
  final LoginCubit loginCubit;
  late final StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  AuthCubit(
      {required this.signOutUseCase,
      required this.loginCubit,
      required this.readAuthFromStorageUseCase,
      required this.isSignInUseCase})
      : super(AuthInitial()) {
    streamSubscription = loginCubit.stream.listen((state) {

//here I listen to Login changes, if the login state is success, then authenticate

      if (state is LoginSuccess) {
        emit(Authenticated(authResponse: state.authResponse));
      }
    });
  }
  Future<void> checkAuthentication() async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
    bool isSignIn = await isSignInUseCase.call();

    if (isSignIn) {
      final AuthResponse authResponse = await readAuthFromStorageUseCase.call();
      emit(Authenticated(authResponse: authResponse));
    } else {
      emit(Unauthenticated());
    }
  }


//close stream sub
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    streamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
```

Since I am listening to `LoginState`, now I can distinguish between the logged-in users and non-logged-in users. According to this, I build my screen as the following.

**main.dart**

```
BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is Authenticated) {
              return const HomeScreen();
            } else if (state is Unauthenticated) {
              return BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                  if (state is LoginFailure) {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => CustomAlertDialog(
                            title: ExceptionConst.exceptionTitle,
                            content: state.appException.message,
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)));
                  }
                },
                child: const LoginScreen(),
              );
            } else {
              return const SplashScreen();
            }
          },
        ));
```

I use `get_it` for di.

**dependency_injection**

```
 sl.registerFactory(() => LoginCubit(loginUserUseCase: sl.call()));
 sl.registerFactory(() => AuthCubit(
      isSignInUseCase: sl.call(),
      loginCubit: sl.call(),
      readAuthFromStorageUseCase: sl.call(),signOutUseCase: sl.call()));

  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => LoginUserUseCase(authRepo: sl.call()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => SignUpUserUseCase(authRepo: sl.call()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => IsSignInUseCase(authRepo: sl.call()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(() => SignOutUseCase(authRepo: sl.call()));
  sl.registerLazySingleton(
      () => ReadAuthFromStorageUseCase(authRepo: sl.call()));
...
```

and lastly this is my `MultiBlocProvider`

```
void main() async {
  await di.init();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
    BlocProvider(create: (_) => di.sl<LoginCubit>()),
    BlocProvider(create: (_) => di.sl<AuthCubit>()..checkAuthentication()),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}
```

However, when I press the login button the `AuthState` is not changing unless I reload the app manually using hot restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing my listening technique from `StreamSubscription` to `BlocListener`. Still, I don't know why the `StreamSubscription` has not worked. Until someone can solve it I will accept my answer.

Here is the solution, I cleaned all `StreamSubscription' codes.

`AuthCubit`

```
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final IsSignInUseCase isSignInUseCase;
  final SignOutUseCase signOutUseCase;
  final ReadAuthFromStorageUseCase readAuthFromStorageUseCase;

  AuthCubit(
      {required this.signOutUseCase,
      required this.readAuthFromStorageUseCase,
      required this.isSignInUseCase})
      : super(AuthInitial());
  Future<void> checkAuthentication() async {
    emit(AuthLoading());
   try{
     bool isSignIn = await isSignInUseCase.call();
     if (isSignIn) {
       final AuthResponse authResponse = await readAuthFromStorageUseCase.call();
       emit(Authenticated(authResponse: authResponse));
     } else {
       emit(Unauthenticated());
     }
   }catch(_){
     emit(Unauthenticated());
   }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    try {
      emit(AuthLoading());
      await signOutUseCase.call();
      emit(Unauthenticated());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(Unauthenticated());
    }
  }
}
```

***main.dart***

```
BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
            builder: (context, authState) {
              if (authState is Authenticated) {
                return const HomeScreen();
              } else if (authState is Unauthenticated) {
                return BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
                  
                  listener: (context, loginState) {
//the following if check make it work. If the LoginSuccess then recheck authentication status.
                    if (loginState is LoginSuccess) {
                      BlocProvider.of<AuthCubit>(context).checkAuthentication();
                    }
                    if (loginState is LoginFailure) {
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => CustomAlertDialog(
                              title: ExceptionConst.exceptionTitle,
                              content: loginState.appException.message,
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)));
                    }
                  },
                  child: const LoginScreen(),
                );
              } else if (authState is AuthLoading) {
                return const Center(
                  child: ButtonSpinner(),
                );
              }
              return const SplashScreen();
            },
          ),
```

finally in my LoginCubit I emit `AuthState`.

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState> {
  final LoginUserUseCase loginUserUseCase;
  final AuthCubit authCubit;

  LoginCubit({required this.authCubit, required this.loginUserUseCase})
      : super(LoginInitial());

  Future<void> loginUser(LoginRequest loginDto) async {
    try {
      emit(LoginLoading());
      final authResponse = await loginUserUseCase.call(loginDto);
      emit(LoginSuccess(authResponse: authResponse));
//if the login process is succeed, then change emit the AuthState as Authenticated.
      authCubit.emit(Authenticated(authResponse: authResponse));
    } on AppException catch (appEx) {
      emit(LoginFailure(appException: appEx));
    }
  }
}
```